# Autostart programs/scripts in Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have a scipt (.sh) for screen rotation of my thinkpad on linux. I have now installed Debian 8 Jessie and the "Startup Applications" is no longer there, how can I make it to startup on boot? or user login?

I have already tried:
1. Create a .desktop for the script and copy it to ~/.config/autostart
2. Copy the script in ~/.config/autostart
3. Create a symlink to the script in ~/.config/autostart

Answer (score 2):

You could also add your script to cron and schedule it to be launched on each reboot. To do this, open the file in an editor:

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

Then add the following line to the end.

```
@reboot root /path/to/script.sh
```

Afterwards just reboot and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If it is reliant on the x-server, then you could add it to `$HOME/.xinitrc`. (I think this is the correct answer)

If it can run without a graphical user interface then put it in the login script (`$HOME/.zlogin` for zsh).

By "it" I mean:

```
bash /path/to/script          #This should be the same as using the following:
#sh /path/to/script           #if it uses #!/usr/bin/sh
#python /path/to/script.py    #if it uses #!/usr/bin/python
#perl /path/to/script.pl      #if it uses #!/usr/bin/perl
#etc
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in .desktop file and it worked OK under ~./config/autostart